# How to ensure that an SPI master sends exactly 16 clock pulses to the slave?

Tags: stm32, spi, current-measurement

I'm using this current sensor: [TLI4970-D050T4](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLI4970-D050T4-DS-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4625607bd1301562c43e04f38ad) According to the datasheet:

[image]

How can the SPI master send exactly 16 clock pulses to the slave, so I don't receive the 0's?

When I'm reading this sensor, I get a lot of 0's. So, I thought that it might be the reason, that I'm sending more than 16 clocks pulses. I'm using an STM32 Nucleo running at 2 MHz, **but the SPI clock has been prescaled to 1 MHz**. I would appreciate any advice. This is the code that I use to read the sensor and calculate current:

```
while (1)
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi1, (uint8_t *)&SPIRx, 2, 10);
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_SET);
motorCurrent=motor_current();

float motor_current() {

    float Iout;
    float BIout;
    int16_t Bit15;
     Bit15 = SPIRx&0x8000;
            if(Bit15==0x8000){
                HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_SET);
            }
            else {
                BIout= SPIRx&0x1FFF;
                Iout = (BIout-4096)/80;
            }
        return Iout;
     }
```

Comment: Are you able to monitor the SPI bus on an o-scope or logic analyzer?

Comment: I could. Just that I don't have the scope right now. It might be next week.

Comment: There's no reason the SPI should send anything other than the number of clock pulses you specify. I just don't see how you're setting it up in the snippet you provided.

Comment: While you're waiting on that scope, you may want to check 4.1.2 in the infineon datasheet and cross-check it with the SPI parameters on your Nucleo to make sure the CS and SCLK setup time is met and that the CPHA, CPOL parameters are good.  I don't know which specific processor you're using, but a 2MHz CPU speed sounds awfully slow, usually peripheral clocking has prescalers to slow down a system clock that the processor runs at.  Last note, the CS and SPI clocking process are usually separate events in terms of code synch, so when you pull that CS low and immediately start the SPI transfer

Comment: you may not meet the infineon's minimum setup time from chip select to first SPI clock pulse if your CPU internal speed is realy fast.

Comment: Do you recommend to increase core clock? I have checked CPHA and CPOL parameters and they are okay.

Comment: No he means to add some delay between system reset and the first reading

Comment: If you send 2 bytes you will send 16 clock pulses for sure. You have another problem there. Check the status word

Comment: Most all SPI engines give the use an option to send 1, 2, 3, or 4 bytes at a time. An 8 bit MPU is organized around moving bytes of data, so you specify bytes to move. A 32 bit MPU defaults to moving 4 bytes at a time. There is no size other than whole bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using HAL_SPI_Receive() wrong, second parameter should be your buffer not SPI register. Other potential problem is that you have short timeout (fourth parameter) with slow SPI clock.

You can also make living easier if you look at your hspi1 configuration and change data size to 16 bits.

EDIT

If second parameter is your buffer and not SPI register, that I would still increase timeout and check if HAL_SPI_Receive() return success or error.

Comment: `SPIRx` does not look like a register definition for STM32. Usually it would be `SPI1->RX`

Comment: You are probably right, but STM32 sometimes use NAMEx in examples

Comment: SPIRx is just a variable a created to store the SPI data.

Comment: Should I read the SPI in the main loop or create a timer based interrupt to read SPI at a fixed frequency?

Comment: depend on what you do with information from sensor, if you want to integrate it then interrupt is better, if you want to only display it then it could be in main loop.

Comment: I'm using this sensor in the emitter leg of a power IGBT switched at 5 kHz PWM. Do you think it's possible to synchronize the PWM on-time with the current measurement?

Comment: Definitely, wire PWM also to one of pins of microprocessor and configure interupt on pin state change.